# Prove that $x\sin A+y\sin B+z\sin C\leqslant \frac{\sqrt{\left( x^2+k \right) \left( y^2+k \right) \left( z^2+k \right)}}{k}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality, triangles, geometric-inequalities

> In triangle $ABC$, let $x,y,z,k>0$, prove that
> $$x\sin A+y\sin B+z\sin C\leqslant \frac{\sqrt{\left( x^2+k \right) \left( y^2+k \right) \left( z^2+k \right)}}{k}$$
> where $k$ satisfies $\frac{x^2}{x^2+k}+\frac{y^2}{y^2+k}+\frac{z^2}{z^2+k}=1$.

The inequality holds when $\sin A:\sin B:\sin C=\frac{x}{x^2+k}:\frac{y}{y^2+k}:\frac{z}{z^2+k}$.

It is said that it's generalization of $x^2+y^2+z^2\geqslant 2xy\cos C+2yz\cos A+2xz\cos B$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\cos B=t\in(-1,1)$ and we shall use the trick of the **expansion of sin C in A, B** and organizing it in the form of $A_1 \sin A+ A_2\cos A +A_3$ so that we can use the Cauchy inequality to turn it into a one-variable problem.
\begin{aligned}
x\sin A+y\sin B+z\sin C&=\left( z\cos B+x \right) \cdot \sin A+z\sin B\cdot \cos A+y\sin B
\\
&\le \sqrt{\left( z\cos B+x \right) ^2+z^2\sin ^2B}+y\sin B
\\
&=\sqrt{z^2+x^2+2xz\cos B}+y\sin B
\\
&=\sqrt{z^2+x^2+2xzt}+y\sqrt{1-t^2}
\end{aligned}

(note that the '=' here can actually be obtained due to the fact that $x,y,z,k$ are positive and $\tan A\in \mathbb{R}$). The following work can be done by solving the zeroes in a $3^{rd}$ degree equation (which is the same degree as the condition itself). I tested several combinations, and the result seems to be correct.

[image: verification]

Nevertheless, I believe the problem has its own more elegent solutions.